# React Native iOS In-App Purchase does not work in Released version

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I've just released (~12 hour ago) an app in the app store that I have added an in app purchase for.

I fully tested it in the sandbox (TestFlight) environment and all worked fine.

But me and other users facing an error like;

They are able to

1. see the products (subscription plans)
2. purchase one of them.
3. see the apple's "success" alert pop-up.
4. see the plans on their Apple Account.

However, in the app, they are not able to unlocked the premium content. or even the useEffect hook is not triggered (which helps users to automatically goBack(). )

I don't understand and know what to do in this situation.

Thank you for all in advance.

*- Platform: IOS 14

- React Native Version: 0.64.2
- Package: react-native-iap 7.2.1*

You can find example code [here](https://gist.github.com/ugenc/a2e71ef21c9527ca8103899ac6e14ca1) that I used. Sorry for the external, I couldn't add a code snippet here properly.

Answer (score 1):

`IAP.validateReceiptIos(receiptBody, true)` has the second parameter set to `true`.

`true` is for Sandbox tests
`false` - for Real (release) payments

After we changed the value to `false` and submitted the app for review, everything works fine.